# Render td's dynamically in xsl

Tags: html, xslt

I am new to xsl and I want to render td's dynamically according to the incoming data. Following is my code which I am using to render rows and column(fixed). But I dont want table to be rendered in this way. I want table to be renderd like 3 columns in a row and if more data is there the it should create a new row and populate td's according to the dynamic data. The below code prints new table with dynamic rows. I want to print dynamic columns instead or rows and the new row should be created if 3 columns are exhausted.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="width:730px; margin:0 auto;">
          <h1 style="height:20px;font:normal 18px Calibri;color:#010101;font-weight:600;border-collapse: collapse; margin-left:20px">
            Related Links
          </h1>
          <div style="width:730px; margin:0 auto;">
          <xsl:for-each select="UserResult/ActivityResults/ActivityResult">
          <xsl:if test="ActivityNameForDisplay != ''">
          <h2 style="padding-left:23px;">
            <xsl:value-of select="ActivityNameForDisplay"/>
          </h2>
            <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="alignTable">
            <xsl:for-each select="Links/RelatedLinks">
                    <tr style="width:100%">     

                    <td style="width:50%">
                      <strong>
                        <xsl:value-of select="LinkName"/> 
                      </strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50%">
                      <strong>
                       <xsl:variable name="hyperlink"><xsl:value-of select="Url"/></xsl:variable>
                        <a href="{$hyperlink}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="Url"/> </a>
                      </strong>
                    </td>
                     </tr>
                     </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to show some input XML and desired output

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT1 or can you use XSLT2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky but possible with XSLT1.  The trick is to do two passes over your data:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Links/RelatedLinks[position() mod 3 = 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="../RelatedLinks[floor((position()-1) div 3) = $pos - 1]">
            <td>
                <!-- Process column cell here -->
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- we can add empty td elements here to fill out the row -->
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In the outer pass we select the first element in each row.  These are the items whose position is one more than a multiple of 3 (the first, fourth, seventh, and so on).  For each of these first items we record the position.  Note that these will be 1, 2, 3, and so on (the row number) as this is in the context of the first items in each row.

In the inner loop, we again pass over all items.  Now we get one less than the position divided by 3 floored (this gives us values of 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, and so on).  Now we check this and see if it matches the row number (which we subtract 1 from to coerce it to 0, 1, 2, and so on).  This gives us all the elements for that row.

This will only add the actual used td elements.  If you require each row to be filled, add the empty td elements where specified with

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(../RelatedLinks[floor((position()-1) div 3) = $pos - 1])"/>
<xsl:if test="$count &lt; 3">
    <td/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$count &lt; 2">
    <td/>
</xsl:if>
```

Here we count the number of elements used in the row and store that as a variable (to avoid having to count it twice).  We then check if we had less than 3 elements.  If so, we add one.  Then we check if we had less than 2.  If so, we add one more (we already added one in this case).  We don't need to check for having added none, because we wouldn't have had a row in that case.

---

This is easier in XSLT 2 using the *for-each-group* operation:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Links/RelatedLinks" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 3">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <td>
                <!-- Process column cell here -->
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- we can add empty td elements here to fill out the row -->
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Here we loop over groups, where the group an item belongs to is determined by taking one less than its position integer-divided by 3.  This gives values of 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, and so on.  Thus each three consecutive items are placed in the same group.  We can then iterate over the group to create the cells.

To add the empty td elements, we can use

```
<xsl:if test="count(current-group()) &lt; 3">
    <td/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="count(current-group()) &lt; 2">
    <td/>
</xsl:if>
```

The logic here is similar to the XSLT1 solution, but we can work with the prebuilt group here.

Comment: Sir, you a pure genius. Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. XSLT 1 worked.

Comment: All working fine. Just a problem. When my table renders in browser, I dont get border for the unfilled td's. Say if the structure in like 1st row 3 td's and 2nd row 1 td. Then for remaining 2 td's of the 2nd row I dont get a border.

Comment: @user2998990 That is because you only have td elements that were actually used.  If you have a row with fewer than 3 items, that row will have fewer than 3 tds in it.  I added to the answer to show how to add these extra empty td elements if desired.

Comment: @user2998990 I added comments to the earlier code showing where to put it.  Put it exactly where the comment `<!-- we can add empty td elements here to fill out the row -->` appears.

Comment: I used your first option. If my links for rendering are more than 4 the in 2nd row I get a blank td.